# How to trigger a docker swarm service update (remotely)?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, portainer

I'm running docker services as stacks on docker systems in swarm mode. To perform rolling updates in the ci/cd pipeline I used the portainer feature: [Webhooks](https://docs.portainer.io/v/ce-2.11/user/docker/services/webhooks). But whenerver I have to update the portainer itself (or the loadbalancer) the webhook gets updated and I have to update all pipelines with the new GUID.

Is there any other way to trigger this update? - Maybe something like [Watchtower](https://containrrr.dev/watchtower/) or [DockerUpdater](https://www.dockupdater.dev/) but which supports docker swarm services?

It doesn't need to be triggered via webhook or remotely. Could also be done like watchtower or maybe traefik - configured with labels.

Comment: usually all you need to do is running `docker stack deploy ...`. If will perform a rolling update on the stack if its already deployed.

Comment: I know, but I would like like to trigger the update when the image was updated. Best case by the cicd pipeline iteself, of a service which checks if there is an update and performing such.

Comment: you can connect to the docker host over http from your pipeline and issue the command there.  https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ServiceUpdate

Comment: @TheFool : You're right. I hoped, I could avoid enabling the http api and make it accessible though the web :(